# Superset: command not found

Tags: database, flask, apache-superset

I have installed superset using `pip install superset` command. Then i try to superset db upgrade but it's saying `superset: command not found`

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through the `superset` documentation [here](https://github.com/ApacheInfra/superset).

First I was trying without installing `superset` package in my virtual environment. After successful installation it's working fine.

Comment: Superset's Dashboard is based on reactJS!!

Comment: This is not providing a solution as it should. Webpages can change so you should provide a minimal working answer here.

Answer (score 4):

From [Superset documentation](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#) you should do this:

> ```
> # Install superset
> pip install superset
>
> # Create an admin user (you will be prompted to set username, first and last name before setting a password)
> fabmanager create-admin --app superset
>
> # Initialize the database
> superset db upgrade
>
> # Load some data to play with
> superset load_examples
>
> # Create default roles and permissions
> superset init
>
> # Start the web server on port 8088, use -p to bind to another port
> superset runserver
> ```

**Note**: Only run this command in a virtual environment, `fabmanager` will not work well if you don't do this.

Answer (score 4):

FYI now the PyPI package is `apache-superset`, so `pip install apache-superset`

Answer (score 2):

For me in Mac OSX launching this command

> virtualenv venv
>       . ./venv/bin/activate

before installing superset:

> pip install superset

worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, so I went to the path of superset and did this.

something like this: `~/.local/bin/superset db upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

As this error just occurred to me, I have finally find a solution based on @sammy ongaya. First need to cd to your virtenvs fold's \Scripts\, like me using conda, so it's under C:\Anaconda3\envs\python35\Scripts. And then just put python before all command, like python superset db upgrade.

After that everything should work. Hope to help someone looking for windows Superset error.

Answer (score 0):

Add `python` before `superset db upgrade` command. Your command should be `python superset db upgrade`. Whenever you run a superset command try adding the `python` before your command.

Answer (score 0):

@moxiao was right, to `cd` to your `virtenvs` fold's *\Scripts* use `cd venv\Scripts\` after

```
virtualenv venv
venv\Scripts\activate
pip install superset
```