# Cron fails with the message Superset: command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, apache-superset

I've installed Superset following the installation guide in the apache superset web page, for Python 3.7.

Even though I can manually start the server, when I'm trying to script the startup steps and cron them, it fails.

The output of the execution is the following:

```
superset: command not found
```

I've read the replies of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513893/superset-command-not-found) but nothing applies to this case.
I'm not using virtualenv for the installation.

These are the output of the which commands:

```
ec2-user@Superset-STAGE /var/spool/mail$which python3
/usr/bin/python3 

ec2-user@Superset-STAGE /var/spool/mail$which superset
~/.local/bin/superset

ec2-user@Superset-STAGE /var/spool/mail$sudo superset
sudo: superset: command not found
```

Would you please guide me on how to have my script working without failure? Script looks like below.

```
superset init
wait
superset runserver -d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron runs as root, which means its home directory is `/root` rather than `/home/ec2-user` as you expect. This means that it will not be able to find `/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/superset` because it neither looks for executables in a `~/.local/bin/superset` nor is it logged in as a user that has such a directory. A quick fix here is to use the full path, but I would recommend moving the executable to a more appropriate directory such as `/usr/local/bin` and then adding it to the PATH variable in `/etc/profile`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Quick fix worked fine. I'll look for more information on how to move the executable and update PATH variable so I can run the command without the full path.